# Angularjs Controller test giving TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs

```js
.controller('ClientsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$filter', '$modal', 'ngTableParams',
      function($scope, $location, $filter, $modal, ngTableParams) {

        var trowser = PY.getBooks($scope, $location, $modal);

      };
```

controllertestspec.js

```js
'use strict';

describe('suite', function() {

  var scope, ctrl;
  beforeEach(module('clients'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    scope = {};
    var modalInstance = jasmine.createSpy('fakeModal');
    ctrl = $controller('ClientsCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $modal: modalInstance
    });
  }));

  it('should change greeting value if name value is changed', function() {

  });

});
```

I have added the js file having module PY and if i try to print console.log(typeof PY.Books) it shows as function.
When i tried to run the spec file am getting error

Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) clients module should change greeting value if name value is changed FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at Object.PY.getBooks

Comment: Where is `PY` defined?  Did you add it to karma.conf.js?

Comment: Yes it is in a js file added to karma config file and also if i put the code  console.log(typeof PY.Books) in my spec it shows as a function which means PY is loading, not sure why controller fails to recognise it

Comment: `jasmine.createSpy('fakeModal');` will not create a spy.  You need at least one `method` to mock.